# Create object using object manager in magento 2

Tags: magento2, object-manager

I want to load that $configLoader without constructor i tried like below, but it's not working please tell me any other way to load that ConfigLoaderInterface without constructor.

```
<?php
namespace NameSpace\Module\Console\Command;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

class CustomCommandClass extends Command
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\State $state,
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ConfigLoaderInterface $configLoader
    ) {
        $state->setAreaCode('frontend'); //SET CURRENT AREA
        $objectManager->configure($configLoader->load('frontend')); //SOLUTION
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

I tried like below without constructor,

```
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');
$configLoader = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ConfigLoaderInterface');
$objectManager->configure($configLoader->load('frontend'));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please try using the object manager to test it even though is not recommended. Dependency injection must be used.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$configLoader = $objectManager->get(\Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ConfigLoaderInterface::class);
$objectManager->configure($configLoader->load('frontend'));
```

Comment: Can you share any link for brief detail about objectmanager?

Comment: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/object-manager.html or https://alanstorm.com/magento_2_object_manager/ i will recommend.

Answer (score 0):

Delete var/generation and clear cache.

Run magento setup:upgrade

It may works!